# How to insert data in DB after doing client validation in Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I am new to Yii2. I have a home page which has two buttons 'Create To Do' and 'Insert To Do'. After clicking on 'Create To Do', a Div is displayed which has a form two text fields and a button 'Insert To Do' on click of insert to do I want to validate the form and then insert the data in DB. Below is my model.php file

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
class InsertToDo extends Model
{
    public $Date;
    public $Description;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
        [['Date','Description'],'required'],
        ['Date','date'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Below is my view file

```
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
$this->title = 'My First Project Home Page';
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use app\models\InsertToDo;
?>
<?php 
$model = new InsertToDo;
$script = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#createToDo').hide();

$('#createToDoLink').click(function(){
    $('#createToDo').fadeIn('slow');
});
});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
<div class="site-index">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" id="createToDoLink">Create To Do &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="createToDo">
    <?php $form = yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'createToDo-form']);?>
    <?php echo $form->field($model,'Date');?>
    <?= $form->field($model,'Description');?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Create To Do',['class'=>'btn btn-success','id'=>'insertToDoButton']) ?>
    <?php yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end();?>
    </div>
```

Please help!

Comment: Show your controller please

Comment: What is your question, what is your problem?